PHPWord crashes after opening , even after autoloader and class is verified
I am having trouble getting phpWord to run, within my plugin.  I have the similar version of PDF, running successfully, but phpOffice and specifically word fails.  Here is the code
function vimeoCreateWORDObject()
{
if (!class_exists('autoload'))
  {
   mmd_DebugLog('if (!class_exists(autoload))');      
  $AutoLoaderCommon = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'PhpOffice/Common/src/Common/Autoloader.php';
  require_once $AutoLoaderCommon ;
   mmd_DebugLog('if (!class_exists(autoload)) -- complete');   
  }
  
 
if (!class_exists('PhpWord'))
{
  mmd_DebugLog('if (!class_exists(PhpWord))');   
  $AutoLoaderWord = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'PhpOffice/PHPWord/src/PhpWord/PhpWord.php';      
  require_once($AutoLoaderWord); 
  mmd_DebugLog('if (!class_exists(PhpWord)) -- complete');   
}
  
$phpWord = new PhpWord();   

return $phpWord;
}

What happens is, when it hits the PhpWord call, the following PHP error occurs:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpWord" not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plug-in/xxxxx.php:665

Any clues why?  I am running on Php version 8.1.  Composer is installed
Since the files in PhpOffice show that Autoloader, runs autoload and bootstrap, also runs autoload and these files are directly from the download, the mystery is puzzling me.
